# Pronoun support in wit.ai?

Tags: wit.ai

Currently I have two stories. Something like this:

```
Story #1
User: How much is Widget X 2000?
Bot: It costs $30.

Story #2
User: Where can I buy Widget X 2000?
Bot: At your local Best Buy.
```

The problem: If a user triggers story #1, they still must explicitly say the name of the product (instead of **it**) to trigger story #2. This is what happens:

```
User: How much is Widget X 2000?
Bot: It costs $30.
User: Where can I buy it?
--error--
```

These answers should not be combined into one story because the order of the questions is never the same. Can Wit.Ai understand pronouns somehow?

Comment: Can you clarify a little more what you're trying to do? You can definitely create the story you've outlined above in Wit.

Answer (score 1):

Wit.ai doesn't provide automatic pronoun resolution at the moment.

Typically you should use the context to store the product the user is talking about, something like:

```
User: How much is Widget X 2000?
Bot-action: context.item = "Widget X 2000"
Bot-send: It costs $30.
User: Where can I buy it?
[here the next bot action will use context.item if no item entity is detected in the sentence]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not using any context, so for the agent is not possible to associate "it" with "Widget X 2000".

Comment: But how can I apply context in a user's question if it's in two different stories? Can you explain more what I'd need to change?